# NSURL encoding using iso-8859-1 instead of UTF8

Tags: iphone

I need to convert a NSString to a NSURL using the iso-8859-1 instead of UTF8 (like here: [Re-encode url from utf-8 encoded to iso-8859-1 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927127/re-encode-url-from-utf-8-encoded-to-iso-8859-1-encoded)) but i don't know how to achieve it.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/català
```

should be

```
http://www.example.com/catal%E1
```

insted of

```
http://www.example.com/catal%C3%A0
```

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the NSString method [stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:)